# Security - Protecting an insert statement from malicious code

Tags: sql, sql-server, security

I'm building a commenting system. The comment is sent to a stored procedure in SQL.

What is the best way to prevent html, script, or SQL queries to be injected into the table? I want to do this server-side.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (UserID, Comment) VALUES (@UserID, @Comment)
```

What would be the best way to deal with the comment field and remove any potential HTML, Scripts, or Queries to prevent attacks? Or to drop the insert if it contains certain characters? Eventually I want the user to be able to insert a link though, which would render in on the site as a clickable link...

Just new to this security stuff and obviously it's important.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What server side language are you using? You should add that as a tag.

Comment: This has been asked a few times. Start here http://kunststube.net/escapism/ . I would say the database is the wrong place to be worrying about HTML and XSS - your HTML output code should deal with that.

Comment: @ChristianStewart - It's asp.net but the method is entirely different than a standard control, so I need to handle it directly in the stored procedure.

Comment: @artbristol I guess I'm more concerned with recognizing malicious attempts before it is even inserted into the DB. I could use replace in SQL but perhaps failing an insert if it detects certain things would be even better. Just new at this. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: What about using check constraints on that field? Do you think this would be an appropriate method? I'd want to block thinks like html tags, script tags, sql type statements etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use parameterised statements (as you appear to be doing) with parameters for all variables and you have nothing to worry about from SQL injection.
2. HTML and JS injections are a concern to do with the page output phase, not database storage. Trying to do HTML escaping or validation in the database layer will be frustrating and fruitless: it's not the right place to be dealing with those concerns, you'll miss or mis-handle data, and the tools for string manipulation in SQL are weak.

Don't think in terms of detecting “attacks”, because blacklists will always fail. Instead aim to handle all text correctly, and then you'll be secure as a side effect of being accurate. Variable text that you drop into an HTML file needs to be HTML-escaped; variable text that you drop into a JavaScript string literal needs to be JS-escaped.

If you're using standard .NET templates, use the `<%:` syntax to HTML-escape text. Use that as your output tag instead of `<%=`  and you'll be fine. Similarly, if you're using WebForms, use the controls whose `Text` property is automatically HTML-escaped. (Unfortunately this is [inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414464/18936).) Where you have to generate markup directly, use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` explicitly.

Encoding for JavaScript string literals is a little trickier. There is `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`, but JS strings commonly live inside HTML `<script>` blocks (making the `</` sequence dangerous where it isn't in native JS), or in HTML inline event handlers (where you would need to JS-encode and *then* HTML-encode as well). It tends to be a better strategy to encode the data you want to send to JS in the DOM using regular HTML-escaping, for example in a `data-` attribute or an `<input type="hidden">`, and have the JS grab the value from the DOM.

If you really have to allow the user to input custom markup, then you'll need to filter it at input time to a small whitelist of approved elements and attributes. Use an existing HTML purifier library.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. This gave me a lot  of clarity. Appreciate the fast and helpful response.